# Разное поведение метода на Android 5 и 4

Tags: android, wifi

Есть метод, который включает WIFI и получает список доступных сетей.

На Android 5 он работает отлично, а вот на 4 (ICS) выдает `NullPointerException`

Сам метод (вызывается через Button)

```
private void wifiSetting() {

    Log.d(TAG, "Wifi status" + wifiEnabled);
    if (!wifiEnabled) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Enabled wifi");
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        wifiEnabled = true;
        //wifiTextView.setText(R.string.wifiOn);
        Log.d(TAG, "Start wifi scan");
        wifiManager.startScan();
        Log.d(TAG, "Get result");
        List<ScanResult> scanResultList = null;
        try {
            scanResultList = wifiManager.getScanResults(); // строка 158
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, scanResultList.toString());
        for (ScanResult result : scanResultList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Add wifi " + result.SSID);
            wifiSsidList.add(result.SSID);
        }
        //handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Disabled wifi");
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        wifiEnabled = false;
        //wifiTextView.setText(R.string.wifiOff);
        wifiSsidList.clear();
        //handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
11-29 12:37:58.928 1125-1125/ru.monochrome.research.rabbitscreenblocker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
      at ru.monochrome.research.rabbitscreenblocker.activities.AgentActivity.wifiSetting(AgentActivity.java:158)
      at ru.monochrome.research.rabbitscreenblocker.activities.AgentActivity.onClick(AgentActivity.java:122)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Пробовал запускать метод в отдельном потоке, но все равно ошибка.

Comment: В доках пишут: `An app must hold ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` Они у вас есть? Добавьте манифест в вопрос.

Comment: такого не может быть. NPE на той строке, которую вы указали, как 158 значит, что `wifiManager == null`. Но вы используете его перед эим 2 раза, и до этого он не являлся равным null. Проверьте, что ошибка именно в этой строке

Comment: @metalurgus, в гугле пишут, что в исходниках этот метод обращается к сервису и при разрыве соединения с ним возвращает null, так что вполне такое возможно.

Comment: Хотя... Если б null вернуло, то ошибка бы не всплыла... Да, проверить надо wifiManager на null;

Comment: В методе onCreate данный механизм отрабатывает и в 4 и в 5 Android, а если вызывать в методе onClick, то возникает ошибка.Через debug null идет с это строчки at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)